# How to ignore jQuery mobile styling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I have a label element which is being created dynamically. When I create it i'm giving it a data-roll attribute with value 'none' and also trying to overide it with my own class which has the '!important' value. Unfortunatley the margin is still being enforced.

Here is an image of the console: https://gyazo.com/26566879cb903304a24b3b313a777c75

CSS:

```
#label {
    margin: 0px !important;
}
```

JS:

```
$("<label />") //create new label
            .attr("id", "label" + listCount) //set ID
            .attr("for", "input" + listCount) //set For
            .attr("class", "inline")
            .attr("data-roll", "none")
            .html(input) //set contents
            .appendTo("#input" + listCount + "container");//add to checkbox container
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
label.inline {
    margin: 0px !important;
}
```

Because your `id` is actually going to be `#labelSOMEnUMBER`, you can't select it with your `id`.